# HighCharts Sankey + NextJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Core/Series/Point.js' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, next.js, sankey-diagram

I am trying to render a [HighCharts Sankey](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram) chart using [HighCharts React](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) and [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/). I've followed HighChart's documentation on how to add the Sankey module, but the page fails with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Core/Series/Point.js' of undefined
```

The error seems to occur at the `addSankeyModule`, before the chart is actually initialized. Below is my module code:

```
import React from "react"
import Highcharts from "highcharts"
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official"
import addSankeyModule from "highcharts/modules/sankey"

addSankeyModule(Highcharts)

const options = {
      // omitted for brevity
}

const DependenciesChart: React.FC = () => (
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
)

export default DependenciesChart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NextJS runs your code twice: first on the server and then later in the browser of the client. This error occurs in the prior situation, where Sankey is trying to initialize itself on the server but fails because it expects a real browser.

To fix this, you can use the following check to conditionally add the module only within the browser:

```
if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  addSankeyModule(Highcharts)
}
```